# Autoref's inserted text has not the correct case

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, capitalization, naming

I'm using the `\autoref` tag which comes with the package **hyperref** for referencing my algorithms, figures etc. I read that it automatically adjusts the reference text's case, but it won't work with my setup. When I compile the code, everything (page, text, link) is correctly put, except the case like in the following example:

> As it can be seen in Figure 9.7, this [...]

Remark: there may be something wrong with my setup - links to text sections (like chapter, section, subsection) and also floating environments like "algorithm" (algorithm2e.sty) do have the correct case. The case is wrong when refering to Figures and Equations.

Comment: Note that it is quite conventional usage to use capital when referring to figures, so it isn't really "wrong" just different. It also avoids the problem of sentence starting.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

`hyperref.sty` indeed includes the following code snippet (with names sometimes, but not always in uppercase):

```
\def\HyLang@english{%
  \def\equationautorefname{Equation}%
  \def\footnoteautorefname{footnote}%
  \def\itemautorefname{item}%
  \def\figureautorefname{Figure}%
  \def\tableautorefname{Table}%
  \def\partautorefname{Part}%
  \def\appendixautorefname{Appendix}%
  \def\chapterautorefname{chapter}%
  \def\sectionautorefname{section}%
  \def\subsectionautorefname{subsection}%
  \def\subsubsectionautorefname{subsubsection}%
  \def\paragraphautorefname{paragraph}%
  \def\subparagraphautorefname{subparagraph}%
  \def\FancyVerbLineautorefname{line}%
  \def\theoremautorefname{Theorem}%
  \def\pageautorefname{page}%
}
```

Solution: Redefine the "offending" name macros.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\renewcommand*{\figureautorefname}{figure}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\rule{1cm}{1cm}
\caption{foo}\label{fig:foo}
\end{figure}

As shown in \autoref{fig:foo}~\dots

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @lockstep, that did the trick for the lowercase-case. BUT when a reference is at the start of a sentence, it's not set uppercase. As far as I know autoref should realize this and set the corresponding case, right?

Comment: @Eric: I'm afraid no. LaTeX can't detect sentence starts automatically; to switch to uppercase manually, you should have a look at the `cleveref` package and its `\cref` and `\Cref` commands.

Comment: Why the last code does not work when the package 'babel' is load... Thanks in advance

Comment: @Gitano See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82993/how-to-change-the-name-of-document-elements-like-figure-contents-bibliogr

Comment: Thanks, very useful information! With the babel package, for me what worked was to use `\addto\extrasenglish{\def\chapterautorefname{Chapter}}` (adding the definitions to `\captionsenglish` didn't work for some reason)

Answer (score 22):

As indicated [by lockstep](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36575/autorefs-inserted-text-has-not-the-correct-case#comment73322_36576) you can use [`cleveref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/cleveref) to have control over case. Simply load `cleveref`, but make sure to load it after `hyperref`, and use `\cref` for lower case cross-references and `\Cref` for upper case cross-references. Other than being able to handle cases `cleveref` can handle ranges of labels and more languages than `\autoref`.

Here is an example on how to use it:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}% Has to be loaded after hyperref

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.48\linewidth]{example-image-a}
  \caption{foo}\label{fig:foo}
\end{figure}

As shown in \cref{fig:foo}~\dots

\Cref{fig:foo} shows~\dots

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of example]

Note that if you want cross-reference links to include the name, e.g. "fig. 1" and not only "1", you have to load `cleveref` with the option `nameinlink`. Also note that if you want it to *not* abbreviate cross-reference names, e.g. "figure 1" and not "fig. 1", you have to load `cleveref` with the option `noabbrev`.