# Fancy cross-referencing

Tags: symbols, cross-referencing, formatting

As an extended idea of [Using section sign (§) for cross-references to sections](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/59889/13747), how can we use

> See ⚙5.2 and ☰5.3 in ☞123.

instead of:

> See figure 5.2 and table 5.3 in page 123.

(Surely there are more appropriate symbols, but because of HTML and font concerns I used these symbols.)

**see also:** [Looking for an appropriate icon for figures, one for tables and one for pages referring](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/60780/13747)

Comment: Love the idea, might adapt it for some documents.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

When using the [`cleveref` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/cleveref) it works exactly like in the link you gave, only you need to change the command to

```
\crefname{figure}{$\alpha$}{$\alpha\alpha$}
\Crefname{figure}{$\alpha$}{$\alpha\alpha$}
\crefname{page}{$\beta$}{$\beta\beta$}
\Crefname{page}{$\beta$}{$\beta\beta$}
\crefname{table}{$\gamma$}{$\gamma\gamma$}
\Crefname{table}{$\gamma$}{$\gamma\gamma$}
```

Just change the symbols. 
`\cref{first figure}` now gives an alpha 1, `\cpageref{fig}` gives an beta {pagenumber here}.

Comment: I shamelessly copied your phrasing, but also gave +1 for your answer & hope that's OK for you.

Answer (score 15):

When using the [`hyperref` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) it works exactly like in Werner's answer at the link you gave, only you need to change the commands to the following:

```
\renewcommand{\figureautorefname}{$\alpha$}
\renewcommand{\tableautorefname}{$\beta$}
\renewcommand{\pageautorefname}{$\gamma$}
```

Just change the symbols. Also see [hyperref's `\autoref`-list by lockstep](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/36576/6865).