# Looking for an appropriate icon for figures, one for tables and one for pages referring

Tags: symbols

Do you know any package that provides appropriate icon for figures, one for tables and one for pages referring(for example a camera and paper icon, `ifsym` package provides a paper icon but is there any more)?

Related to this question: [Fancy cross-referencing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/59938/13747)

Although I accepted an answer new suggestion are welcomed!

Comment: For a camera icon see also [Is there a \camera symbol?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/118955).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`fontawesome`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fontawesome) package offers access to icons included in [Font Awesome](http://fontawesome.io/) project. It works with `XeTeX` or `LuaTeX`. (Update: `fontawesome` also works with pdflatex since [version 4.3.0](http://ctan.org/ctan-ann/id/mailman.2422.1436549478.4386.ctan-ann@dante.de))

Requested icons looks like:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{lc}
\toprule
Command & Icon \\
\midrule
\verb+\faCamera+ & \faCamera \\
\verb+\faCameraRetro+ & \faCameraRetro \\
\verb+\faTable+ & \faTable \\
\verb+\faFile+ & \faFile \\
\verb+\faFileAlt+ & \faFileAlt \\
\verb+\faPicture+ & \faPicture \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 26):

By viewing [`ifsym.sty`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/ifsym/ifsym.sty) it is clear that `\PaperPortrait` requires you to load

```
\usepackage[misc]{ifsym}% http://ctan.org/pkg/ifsym
```

Following the advise of [Symbol or dingbat of a calculator?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/40103/5764), [The Noun Project](http://thenounproject.com/noun/camera/#icon-No106) provides some camera SVG images.

[image]

Additionally, [OpenClipArt](http://openclipart.org) also provides some [camera SVG images](http://openclipart.org/search/?query=camera).

These can be converted to other acceptable image formats (like PDF or TikZ) for inclusion in your document. See [How to include SVG diagrams in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2099/5764)

Comment: Somewhere I read that you are making a package from icons of Noun Project, is it correct?

Comment: @Reza: I mentioned something in [my interview](http://tex.blogoverflow.com/2012/01/textalk-an-interview-with-werner) about making a package related to graphics, but not something about the Noun Project.

Comment: @Reza: I think perhaps you are thinking of doncherry's comment about Martin Scharrer's at [Symbol or dingbat of a calculator?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40095/symbol-or-dingbat-of-a-calculator/40103#40103).

Comment: @PeterGrill Yes, It's right