# Is there a \camera symbol?

Tags: graphics, symbols

I would like to add camera symbol to headwords with photos (sometimes the photos are placed just bellow the headword, sometimes on the other page) so the user of dictionary can find certainly the photos. Is there a nice camera symbol, something like `\Bicycle` symbol etc. ? If no, what is the best way to do it?

[image: Illustration]

The picture above illustrates using `png` picture, but the height of the line is enlarged.

Comment: Please, take a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60780/looking-for-an-appropriate-icon-for-figures-one-for-tables-and-one-for-pages-re

Comment: there is some sort of camera symbol in the unicode: 0xF0 (UTF8 hex)

Comment: but you will need a font that supports this char like Symbolia

Comment: @Papiro I have looked at [question] (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60780/looking-for-an-appropriate-icon-for-figures-one-for-tables-and-one-for-pages-re) and have read how to include svg pictures to LaTex. I will post an answer with result. Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you can work with `XeLaTeX` or `LuaLaTeX`, [`fontawesome`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fontawesome) package provides `\faCamera` and `\faCameraRetro` icons. (Update: `fontawesome` also works with pdflatex since [version 4.3.0](http://ctan.org/ctan-ann/id/mailman.2422.1436549478.4386.ctan-ann@dante.de))

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage{verbatim}

\begin{document}

\verb+fontawesome+ package includes (\verb+\faCamera+) \faCamera\ and (\verb+\faCameraRetro+) \faCameraRetro.

\end{document}
```