# How to define a new hyperref for Functions?

Tags: hyperref, overleaf

My question relates to [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36575/autorefs-inserted-text-has-not-the-correct-case?rq=1). I am trying to define new commands for hyperref. For example, I want to have some equations to be called: Function, Constraint, or Constraint Set. To do it, I tried to follow the instructions provided in the hyperlink.

```
\def\HyLang@english{%
      \def\functionautorefname{Function}%
      \def\conssetautorefname{Constraint set}%
      \def\consautorefname{Constraint}%
    }
```

And, I failed using it as follows:

```
\begin{equation}\label{consset:sum_all=1}
    y_j^A+y_j^I+y_j^P=1 \qquad \forall j\in J
\end{equation}

\autoref{consset:sum_all=1} ensures that everything is alright!
```

which still prints as:

Equation `(<eq number>)` ensures that everything is alright!

while I want:

Constraint set `(<eq number>)` ensures that everything is alright!

Is there any quick solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\autoref` cannot know what type of object you're referring to.

You can use `cleveref` that's more customizable and more powerful.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\crefformat{equation}{#2Equation~\textup{(#1)}#3} % by default eq. (<eq>) is used
\crefformat{constraint}{#2Constraint~\textup{(#1)}#3}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{eq}
equation
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}\label[constraint]{co}
constraint
\end{equation}

We can refer to \cref{eq} and to \cref{co}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I was seeing some bad comments about cleveref and was avoiding it. But, it looks like, it is really clever! Thanks!

Comment: @user8028576 To the contrary, `cleveref` is really, well, clever. `;-)`